# x-editable error 419 in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, x-editable

I try to change value of my column in users table with `x-editable` and I get `419` error on network.

## codes

here is my `CONTROLLER`

```
public function changeprimaryaddress(Request $request){
      try {
          $id = $request->input('pk');
          $field = $request->input('name');
          $value = $request->input('value');

          $user = User::findOrFail($id);
          $user->{$field} = $value;
          $user->save();
      } catch (Exception $e) {
          return response($e->getMessage(), 400);
}
```

my `ROUTE`

```
Route::post('/changeprimaryaddress','UserController@changeprimaryaddress')->name('changeprimaryaddress');
```

my `HTML` code

```
<a href="#"
class="change"
data-type="select"
data-name="address_id"
data-pk="{{ $user->id }}"
data-value="{{ $user->address_id }}"
data-title="Select New Primary Address"
data-url="{{ route('changeprimaryaddress') }}">Change</a>
```

my `JAVASCRIPT`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.change').editable({
        source: [
            @foreach($addresses as $address)
                { value: '{{ $address->id }}', text: '{{ $address->address }} - {{$address->city->name}}, {{$address->state->name}}, {{$address->country->name}}, {{$address->postalcode}}' }
                @unless ($loop->last)
                    ,
                @endunless
            @endforeach
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

## screenvideo

If you like to see the process and errors i provided small video you can see.

[result](https://streamable.com/6eob8)

any idea why is that?

Comment: You need to add CSRF token while post request is sent

Comment: @SagarGautam thanks. i added `$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });` its working now

Comment: Any way congrats man and please close the question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @SagarGautam. I added

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
});
```

its working now.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not sending csrf token to the controller. either send the token, or do the following to exclude it.

open your `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` file, and put the below code:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'changeprimaryaddress',
    ];
}
```

Comment: CSRF protection is necessary from security point of view while accessing the database, I think this is not the good way to do so.

Comment: @SagarGautam, agreed, but if i dont want it, i can exclude